# Django - assign value inside a queryset object dinamically

Tags: python, django

My function read data from DB and return serialized JSON data, my need is add a dinamic field to the queryset.

Actually I'm having trouble adding a field dinamically in a queryset, under the code :

```
def get_sim_list():
  t_sim = RD_sim_list.objects.all()
  for sim in t_sim :
    sim.sim_assigned = 1
  return serializers.serialize('json',t_sim)
```

When I get result value "sim_assigned" does not exist on t_sim object as field.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

:)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that django `serializers` only translate fields that belong to django model objects, but it won't pick up any additional information that doesn't belong to it. So you might need to do it manually with `json.dumps` method instead.

Answer (score -1):

The default serializers provided by Django probably introspect the model and identify what fields need to be serialized. If you are adding a custom attribute, it is likely to not be recognized by the serializer.

I see two options:

1. Write a custom serializer and use that
2. Use the `.values()` method on the queryset and use `json.dumps()` on that.

Example for option 2:

```
import json
t_sim = RD_sim_list.objects.values()
for sim in t_sim :
    sim['sim_assigned'] = 1
return json.dumps(t_sim)
```

Note that you will probably run into errors if your models contain fields with values that are not immediately JSON-convertible (for example, references to other models).